# Loop a Groupby to a Figure, then Subplot by Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I wanna subplot a dataframe groupby. But before that I also want to loop from a major groupby. Take this for example:

```
Year State      Person    Value
2011 California A         12879
2011 California B         10572
2011 California C         8645
2011 California D         9573
2011 Florida    A         8645
2011 Florida    B         9573
2009 California A         8764
2009 California B         9864
2009 California C         9573
2009 California D         12879
2009 Florida    A         9573
2009 Florida    B         10572
```

I want all to be `groupby` by State after that, I want to have a subplot of each Person's value vs. Year. So 1 `figure` per State then a subplot depending on the number of Person.

Here's a csv format:

```
Year,State,Person,Value
2011,California,A,12879
2011,California,B,10572
2011,California,C,8645
2011,California,D,9573
2011,Florida,A,8645
2011,Florida,B,9573
2009,California,A,8764
2009,California,B,9864
2009,California,C,9573
2009,California,D,12879
2009,Florida,A,9573
2009,Florida,B,10572
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a dataset, but you've forgotten to show what you have tried so far, or what research you have done.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was rude of me. I can only do a groupby then plot. But I dont wanna obstruct nicer, faster solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byState=df.groupby('State')
for name, df in byState:
    byPerson = df.groupby('Person')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(len(byPerson)*2,4), nrows=1, ncols=len(byPerson))
    fig.suptitle(name)
    subplot_targets = zip(byPerson.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
    for key, ax in subplot_targets:
        ax.plot(byPerson.get_group(key).index, byPerson.get_group(key).Value)
        ax.set_title(key)
```

[image]